# Прослушивание на http://..... не выполняла ни одна конечная точка,

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, config

Добрый день. У меня есть `WCF` служба, которая используется как клиент для одного вэб-сервиса (ВС) и передает полученные данные уже клиентам для моей wcf службы. В конфиге указал конечную точку для ВС

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://......./" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" 
            contract="ServiceReference1.WebService"
            name="basicHttp" />
</client>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

И при тестировании получаю ошибку: 
Additional information: Прослушивание на `https://........../` не выполняла ни одна конечная точка, которая могла бы принять сообщение. Среди прочих причин это могло быть вызвано неправильным адресом или действием `SOAP`.

Также, чтобы проверить данную конечную точку, я создал просто консольное приложение на котором проверил ее, и для ВС она рабочая. Из чего сразу же конечно вопрос, почему из консольного приложения обратиться к ВС получается, а через `WCF` возникает исключение. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Выразите свою мысль яснее. Понятно, что у вас есть некоторая служба WCF (я буду называть её служба1), которая запрашивает другую службу (я буду называть её служба2, а вы её называете веб-сервис или ВС). Т.е. вы фактически проксируете запросы:  службы1 создаёт клиента к службе2. Допустим. А вот когда вы переходите к третьему абзацу становится совершенно непонятно, что вы считаете "данной конечной точкой", что эмулирует консольное приложение и почему вы вдруг говорите "для ВС она рабочая", как будто у вас уже не служба1 обращается к службе2, а а служба2 вдруг начала вызывать службу1.

Comment: При этом один раз вы совершенно спокойно написали консольное приложение со службой и правильно написали app.config, где правильно описали конфигурацию кто чему клиент и где сервер -- а когда вы пишете это же самое, но службой -- у вас проблемы. При этом кода вы не приводите, поэтому ориенироваться на текст.

Comment: `address="https...` и при этом `<basicHttpBinding>`. Не пойдёт.

Comment: @Zufir у многих работает

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил, оказалось что есть прозрачный прокси, который блочил wcf сервису выход в сеть. Указав его в конфиге все заработало. Всем спасибо.